# JUnit testing result of a program

Tags: java, arrays, junit, javabeans

This is a very basic question for JUnit testing. I wrote a program which calculate the new position of a dot by given instructions for moving. The program is working properly but I have to write a JUnit test for check the result and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a test method for every dot movement that you want to check. In each test method you call your method and then compare the actual result with the expected result.

Try something like this, using JUnit 4.x :

```
package org.dotmover;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DotMoverTest {

    @Test
    public void testDotMoverForward() {
        final DotMover dotMover = new DotMover(...);
        final int newPos = dotMover.move(...);
        final int expectedNewPos = ...;
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedNewPos, newPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add JUnit to classpath of you project. The create JUnit testcase. It is just a class that extends TestCase.

If you are using JUnit prior to v 4.0 each test method must start from word `test`, e.g.
`testPosition()`, `testMoviing()` etc. 
If you are using version 4 and higher the test methods must be targeted with annotation @Test.

Now write your testing scenario. User static `assertXXX()` methods of class `Assert` to verify that your program is working.

Good luck and happy TDD!